# Is there any way to filter only .png files via any method?

Tags: grep, command

I have few lines of codes and I only want to filter the .png files with different names.
For example I have code like this which are shown below. Now I only want to filter the file names with .png extension and the result I want is shown just below.

Any kind of method is appreciated I am desperately working on this solution and didn't find the perfect way to do it.

**Result I want:**

*game/objects/rock_2_shadow.**png**,
game/objects/stump_shadow.**png**, game/objects/tv.**png** and so on...*

**This is the code:**

```
{ bytes: 4531, md5: "DLKvNDSl0Q3y0tlFGNol_A", name: "game/objects/rock_2.png" }, { bytes: 4208, md5: "z1v6RXDu0F6WXFyyBGsBKg", name: "game/objects/rock_2.webp" }, { bytes: 741, md5: "DlK9Ugd6e5L-99V-ryGoiA", name: "game/objects/rock_2_shadow.png" }, { bytes: 448, md5: "e68ha5bvslyYsG_8Kr1dtQ", name: "game/objects/rock_2_shadow.webp" }, { bytes: 3125, md5: "t3eBjoR_9QzrRMgJzlgWCA", name: "game/objects/rock_3.png" }, { bytes: 2670, md5: "z_w1xtubTBXfp0DHun_pHQ", name: "game/objects/rock_3.webp" }, { bytes: 618, md5: "c-l97Wj4nZySEnf2XBAt1Q", name: "game/objects/rock_3_shadow.png" },
                        { bytes: 358, md5: "SJ49Ew6HkE_p02XywWjScA", name: "game/objects/rock_3_shadow.webp" }, { bytes: 4746, md5: "OSK4VYwv_rAdto2dRIgQzg", name: "game/objects/rock_4.png" }, { bytes: 4254, md5: "XkG3_lsGLNIbldhgYQzvkQ", name: "game/objects/rock_4.webp" }, { bytes: 737, md5: "zu4RoYT2e32KZ5IBi1zFwg", name: "game/objects/rock_4_shadow.png" }, { bytes: 444, md5: "S5lQ1bd3RhP4oubg-Zgzfw", name: "game/objects/rock_4_shadow.webp" }, { bytes: 8121, md5: "CabdI9rn-lvkEiEDDUw1XQ", name: "game/objects/stump.png" }, { bytes: 7848, md5: "NerEGkPWl7aGm5vExwUf5g", name: "game/objects/stump.webp" },
                        { bytes: 980, md5: "ipcG0uMYI9BG8FM8fK6k_Q", name: "game/objects/stump_shadow.png" }, { bytes: 666, md5: "fkLA18GD8gItBTbOVJnPog", name: "game/objects/stump_shadow.webp" }, { bytes: 13840, md5: "v6Nxnc6mADteI8cxC_GPiA", name: "game/objects/table.png" }, { bytes: 13144, md5: "xiMMaXe48fR5QLQ0DCD2qw", name: "game/objects/table.webp" }, { bytes: 1556, md5: "FVUAV5dhR4uwaCNkfgkQJg", name: "game/objects/table_shadow.png" }, { bytes: 1092, md5: "XLhQsppcDFFPlADxuhATEw", name: "game/objects/table_shadow.webp" }, {
                            name: "game/objects/tv.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very ugly but if you put all your data in a file called `data.json` you can run the following cide which:

- converts all commas into linefeeds
- looks for the string `name:`
- prints whatever follows in double quotes

---

```
tr , '\n' < data.json | awk -F'"' '/name:/{print $2 }'

game/objects/rock_2.png
game/objects/rock_2.webp
game/objects/rock_2_shadow.png
game/objects/rock_2_shadow.webp
game/objects/rock_3.png
game/objects/rock_3.webp
game/objects/rock_3_shadow.png
game/objects/rock_3_shadow.webp
game/objects/rock_4.png
game/objects/rock_4.webp
game/objects/rock_4_shadow.png
game/objects/rock_4_shadow.webp
game/objects/stump.png
game/objects/stump.webp
game/objects/stump_shadow.png
game/objects/stump_shadow.webp
game/objects/table.png
game/objects/table.webp
game/objects/table_shadow.png
game/objects/table_shadow.webp
game/objects/tv.png
```

You can add an extra filter for `png` easily enough.

---

You may find this simpler. It transliterates all double quotes into newlines and looks for lines ending in `.png`

```
tr '"' '\n' < data.json | grep "\.png$"
```

---

If your data is stored in a `bash` variable called `data` rather than in a file called `data.json`, just use this syntax:

```
echo "$data" | tr '"' '\n' | grep "\.png$"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Eo '[0-9a-z_/]+\.png' your_file.txt
```

or

```
printf 'paste your code here' | grep -Eo '[0-9a-z_/]+\.png'
```

Output:

```
game/objects/rock_2.png
game/objects/rock_2_shadow.png
game/objects/rock_3.png
game/objects/rock_3_shadow.png
game/objects/rock_4.png
game/objects/rock_4_shadow.png
game/objects/stump.png
game/objects/stump_shadow.png
game/objects/table.png
game/objects/table_shadow.png
game/objects/tv.png
```